# Not able to install BZIP2 1.0.6 version in Red Hat server

Tags: redhat, bzip2

I am trying to install the latest version of bzip2 in an RHEL server. The current version of bzip2 installed is 1.0.5 and is not useful for my purposes.

The 1.0.6 version of bzip2 is available from 
http://www.bzip.org/downloads.html

Commands

```
tar xzvf bzip2-1.0.6.tar.gz
cd bzip2-1.0.6
vim README
```

README section screenshot:

[image]

[image]

So I do

```
make -f Makefile libbz2_so
make
make install
```

This doesn't seem to work out for me.

The output from `make install` is:

[image]

Comment: it would be useful if you could add *what* doesn't work or what error messages you get. My crystal ball is off for repair atm

Comment: Please see the output from make install command. Screenshot is attached.

Comment: That screenshot unfortunately doesn't answer any of the above.

Comment: Agreed that an error message or what is not working would be super helpful, but my crystal ball is telling me the bzip in `/usr/bin` is taking preference over this one installed in `/usr/local/bin` and that is causing the 'not working for me'.

Comment: How do I correct it?